# I need to centre my captions and figure with respect to the text, not the page but it keeps ignoring the margin conditions

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, captions

Here is my report:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

Here is a figure:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{content_before_after}
\caption{Thermal desorption analysis data of SCM420 H steel subjected to hydrogen ingress from the decomposition of two different oil compositions, the composition of which were undisclosed \cite{19}.}
\label{fig:content_before_after}
\end{figure}
```

The results:

[image]

What I want is to have the figure and caption centred to the text and NOT how it is now, to the page! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I cant reproduce your problem. So, please compose from your codes fragments one, complete document, which we can copy and compile in our PC, and which will show your problem.

Comment: The code snippets do not reveal the relevant code to reproduce the problem. The figure and caption look correct regarding the page margins. The text, however, seems to be indented (maybe the text is currently inside an item of a list or whatever.  Floating entities like figures do *not* follow the surrounding text lines. Often they refer to a different part of the text. They are using the full text width in a one-column layout.

Answer (score 2):

The floats as the `figure` environment always have a width equal to    `\textwidth` or `\columnwith` (that in one column document is the same value, by default 345pt in the article document class).

Another length is `\linewidth`, that by default is again the same (also 345pt). But if you make a list or something else reducing the width of text, most probably you not changed `\textwidth` nor `\columnwith` but `\linewidth`. For example, within an itemize environment `\linewidth` change to roughly 320pt but `\columnwith` still remain in 345pt).

Then, you have at least two options:

1. Use a float, but internally reduce the available space for images and caption to the actual `\linewidth`. Then you need take that dimension in text, close to the final float position, and store it as a new length (said `\lwr`) because inside the float `\linewidth` will return to the original value. Finally you can use a right aligned `\parbox` or a `minipage`  environment with a width equal to  \lwr).
2. No not use a float, but the `capt-of` package. The caption simply will take the width of the actual `\linewidth` and little captions will be centered automatically.  For the image use a width equal to `\linewidth` or  some less for centered images, but never ever use other relative length that `\linewidth`. This always work, whilst using `\textwith` or `\columnwidth` maybe work, or maybe left and image bigger that the expected.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of} % do not use caption package in this case
\usepackage{xcolor} % just to show the margin
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\captext{Some caption text that will fill more 
than one line of this wonderfull example.}
\newlength{\lwr}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item\makebox(0,-50)[t]{\color{red!20}\rule{2pt}{11cm}}% 
\setlength{\lwr}{\linewidth}%
\lipsum[4] % dummy text with some indentation

% Figure that take the full width:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{\captext}
\end{figure}

% Alternative with float
\begin{figure}[h]
\hfill\parbox{\lwr}{
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{\captext}}
\end{figure}

% Alternative without float 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{\captext}
\lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```